# Visual Studio C++ Multi-Project Solutions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I typically use Linux to do all of my development, but have to use Visual Studio (2013 Professional, if that matters) for the project I'm working on now. I've used Visual Studio for projects in the past, and set up multi-project solutions where there were .lib and .dll files generated and all linked together by the compiler at the end to make an executable, or several. However, I've only ever set up these projects through the strange process of setting up dependencies, adding one project's directory to another projects include directory, adding the the library to the dependent projects linked libraries, etc. I'm used to the way Eclipse does this, where it give you a list of all the projects in your working set, and you can select what projects a given one is dependent on, and it will set all of this up for me. I've searched around and found nothing on how to do this simply in Visual Studio like I can in Eclipse. Is there no way to simply automate this task without resorting to the extreme of writing my own add-on, or is there one like this already in existence that I've yet to find?

Edit: I am referring to C++ projects

Comment: What kind of projects are these? C++?

Comment: Yes. (need more characters)

Comment: In the future, use the [tag:c++] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a project-to-project reference in:
Common Properties/Framework and References

According to Microsoft, adding the Reference in Framework and References is the preferred method in Visual Studio 2010 and later.  More info here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/02/16/project-settings-changes-with-vs2010.aspx

Comment: This doesn't set up the include directory and the linker to make visual studio actually link with the other project, at least in C++.

Comment: I just tried this in Visual Studio Professional 2013. I have a project "MathLibrary" and another "MathLibrary_Test." I set "MathLibrary" to be a dependency of "MathLibrary_Test." I then tried to use the code "#include <vec4.h>" which gives a compiler error "vec4.h could not be found." I tried adding the include directory to the project manually, which worked, and then it gave me a linker warning for the constructor of an object I was trying to test. I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I started a solution and 2 projects from scratch and had the same problems as you.  It looks like you have to add a reference in the "Common Properties/Framework and References" project properties instead.  Oddly, I don't remember having to do that before.

Comment: Now it works! So I have to set the include directory manually?

Comment: I think so.  I don't know of any way to automatically add include directories.

Comment: You can do solution level include directories.  So, at least you would only have to add the directories in 1 place for each solution.  If you add another library, you could just add the new directory to the solution include directories and then the old project and the new project would all automatically inherit all of the include directories.

Comment: Alternatively to solution level include folders, you can use property sheets. This way you can have whatever hierarchy of inherited include folders (and other settings) you like, rather than having the same include folders apply to all projects in your solution (some of which they might not be relevant to). Place common settings in property sheet(s), then add them to whichever projects they apply to.